# Adding Magic Cookie data to an AAC file?

Tags: ios, audio, cookies, aac

I'm trying to wrap my head around magic cookies in AAC files. I'm attempting to write a unit test for an iPhone application (for some code I didn't write) to test magic cookies inside an AAC file which we are later streaming, but I'm struggling to find a file to test it with. I've tried converting wave files to AAC using Audacity, Adapter, etc., but the method is always returning an `OSStatus` of 1836020325, which corresponds to `kAudioFileStreamError_DataUnavailable`. This presumably means that the file I provided doesn't have magic cookie data inside it. I'm trying to access the information with `kAudioFileStreamProperty_MagicCookieData`.

I think my question is: is there some specific way to add magic cookie data to an AAC file, or should a standard conversion of a wave file create this information?